# Word for "without asking for it"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, prepositions

Is there any word in place of *without asking for it* in the following example?

> If you want to learn how to get a job offer **without asking for it**, buy this book.

The word *spontaneous* popped into my mind, but it doesn't seem right because, in the above example, the event isn't really spontaneous as the other party consciously chose to offer the other person a job, without the job-seeker having asked for it first.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*[Unsolicited](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unsolicited)* is the closest single-word synonym I could think of; however, it has a drawback when applied to this scenario: it can have the connotation of *unwanted*.  Upon analysis, *without asking for it* does not fit the intended meaning here either, as it carries the same drawback. The best option is to rephrase:

> If you want people to start offering you jobs, buy this book.
>
> If you want to start getting job offers without even applying [for them], buy this book.
>
> Turn the tables on finding employment - get jobs to look for you!
>
> Tired of searching for a job?  Let the job find you! [courtesy @ajk]

Comment: Unsolicited sounds like the closest single word, but you're right about the connotation. It doesn't seem to fit with the asker's purpose. Taglines like 'tired of searching for a job? let the job find you!' are not exactly original, but feel like a closer fit for the asker's intent.

Comment: *Without asking for it* doesn't fit either.  *Unsolicited* tends to fit wherever *without asking for it* fits.

Answer (score 1):

You could try *snatch*:

> If you want to learn how to snatch a job offer, buy this book.

I was often told off as a child for snatching, because I should ask first.

Comment: I feel like this implies you're stealing away the job, possibly from more qualified applicants.  At least, it's not very close to the OP's intent at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using *headhunted*.

Comment: Why would you want to learn to get a headhunted job offer?  I can't get my head around how you could incorporate this word into the OP's example.